# Getting the controller for a form in magento

Tags: magento

I have this action defined in my form.phtml (Environment is magento).

form action="getUrl('contacts/index/post')

Now I need to know which controller is getting called so I can get the values in the backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is pretty straight forward.
The first word `contacts` is the front-name which in magento standards is the module name. The second word `index` is the controller file name and the last word `post` is the action of the controller.

Because thats a core controller, you can find the file under `/app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php`

Look at the `postAction()` function.

Comment: Yeah, I already figured that out. Can you answer my next question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35274030/value-not-getting-bind-in-the-magento-controller

Comment: _The first word contacts is the front-name which in magento standards is the module name._ : Is  maybe too much simplified. The front name is actually stated in the `config.xml` of each module, in the section where you define the `<routers>` of your module.

Comment: @b.enoit.be yes indeed