# Value not getting bind in the Magento controller

Tags: magento

This is the predefined post function inside Magento controller.

```
public function postAction()
{
    $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();


    if ( $post ) {
        $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
        /* @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
        $translate->setTranslateInline(false);
        try {
            $postObject = new Varien_Object();
            $postObject->setData($post);

            $error = false;

            if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }

            if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                //$error = true; //orignal code
                  $error = false;

            }

            if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
                $error = true;
            }
            Mage::log($post['producturl']);
            if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['producturl']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }

            //if (Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['hideit']), 'NotEmpty')) {
              //  $error = true;
            //}
            Mage::log($error);

            Mage::log($postObject);
            if ($error) {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
            /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
            $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                ->sendTransactional(
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
                    null,
                    array('data' => $postObject)
                );

            if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
                throw new Exception();
            }

            $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.'));
            $this->_redirect('');

            return;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }

    } else {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
}
```

When I log the producturl attribute, it prints the correct view.But I do not get that value in my email. How to get that value binded so it gets send to the email?

My form looks like this:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('contacts/index/post'); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post">
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <!--<label for="name" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Name') ?></label>-->
            <div class="input-box">
                <input name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name*" title="<em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Name') ?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->helper('contacts')->getUserName()) ?>" class="input-text required-entry" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <!--<label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email') ?></label>-->
            <div class="input-box">
                <input name="email" id="email"  placeholder="Email*" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email') ?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->helper('contacts')->getUserEmail()) ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <!--<label for="telephone" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Mobile') ?></label>-->
            <div class="input-box">
                <input name="telephone" id="telephone" placeholder="Mobile*" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Telephone') ?>" value="" class="input-text required-entry" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-12">

            <div class="input-box">
                <input name="producturl" id="producturl" placeholder="Product URL*" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('ProductURL') ?>" value="url hai bhai" class="input-text required-entry" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <!--<label for="comment" class=""><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?></label>-->
            <div class="input-box input-textarea">
                <textarea name="comment" id="comment" rows="3" placeholder="Message" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?>" class=" input-text" placeholder="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?>" style="width: 100%; height: 15%;resize:none;"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="text-align: center">
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="padding-top:2%">
            <input type="text" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="url hai bhai" style="display:none !important;" />
            <button type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('BOOK A DESIGNER') ?></span></span></button>
        </div>
</div>
</div>

    </div>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? From what I understood you're trying to add a product attribute, to the email body?

Comment: its not a product attribute, its product url, whenever I press submit, i get name, telephone and comment in my email but I do not get product url. I also want product url in my email. I have also added the form which is being used. Right now the product url textbox has hardcoded value.

Comment: Are you using that form on the product view page?

Comment: yes, I am using there

Comment: That maybe a missing part of your copy past but I don't see your form being closed anywhere

Comment: And you actually need to edit and add this value to your mail template, where is it ? I don't see it in your question body.

Comment: where do I find the mail template?and where do I add it. Where is the message body formed in the controller, I cannot find or understand this: setDesignConfig function

Comment: Ok your problem is bigger than you think then. ```Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE)``` is the actual code of the email template you are trying to send. Log that somewhere and we may be able to help you further.

Comment: you mean do this : Mage::log(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE). Logging this gives me: contacts_email_email_template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the emails templates are html files that you can actually find in the folder `app/locale/[some_locale]/template/` if your locale is english of the US then `some_locale` will be `en_US`, if that is french from Belgium, then it will be `fr_BE`, so that is the language code on 2 letter as defined by [ISO 639-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-1) then an underscore `_` and country code as defined by [ISO 3166-1 alpha-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2).

And the name of the file will be something you could find if you do a global search on the handle of the template you actually stated in you comment.

So here `contacts_email_email_template` is actually defined in `app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/etc/config.xml` as being the file `contact_form.html` :

```
<template>
    <email>
        <contacts_email_email_template translate="label" module="contacts">
            <label>Contact Form</label>
            <file>contact_form.html</file>
            <type>text</type>
        </contacts_email_email_template>
    </email>
</template>
```

So if you go and edit `app/locale/en_US/template/email/contact_form.html` that I reproduced here below and in which I added your product url value, that should work :

```
<!--@subject Contact Form@-->
<!--@vars
{"var data.name":"Sender Name",
"var data.email":"Sender Email",
"var data.telephone":"Sender Telephone",
"var data.comment":"Comment"}
@-->
Name: {{var data.name}}
Email: {{var data.email}}
Telephone: {{var data.telephone}}

Comment: {{var data.comment}}
<!-- this below line is actually what you are after -->
Product URL : {{var data.producturl}}
```

`data`, actually being the key of the array you are passing as the fifth argument of the function `sendTransactional`

Answer (score 0):

Well if you wish add the product URL to the email you first need to get the product key and wrap it around the static getUrl function.

```
Mage::getUrl($_product->getUrlKey())
```

Next just assign the above code to a variable and use some jQuery / Javascript to append the url to the end of the content of the message body. Honestly I would not recommend you to do this.